# Particular Solution PDE .

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following :
$$ u_{xx}-u_{xy}+u_{y}-u=cos(x+2y)+e^y   : u=u(x,y)$$ the par1ticular solutuion for the part $ e^y$ :
$$\frac{1}{D_{1}^2-D_{1}D_{2}+D_{2}-1}e^y=\frac{1}{(D_{1}-1)(D_{1}-D_{2}+1)}e^y$$
I had to deal first with :
$$(D_{1}-D_{2}-1)u =e^y$$
then dealing with 
$$\frac{1}{D_{1}-1}u $$ 
I wonder if there is a short solution which I haven't noticed ?

Thank you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $$ u=\frac{1}{(D_{1}-1)(D_{1}-D_{2}+1)}e^y$$
which implies $$u_{xx}-u_{xy}+u_{y}-u=e^y \ (1)$$
let $ u(x,y)=f(x)e^y$ So we have :
$$f''(x)e^y-f'(x)e^y+f(x)e^y-f(x)e^y=e^y \Rightarrow f''(x)-f'(x)-1=0 $$
which implies:
$$ f(x) =-x $$
finally $$u =-xe^y $$